# Createing Album using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an album in some Facebook test users using V2.2. I tried couple of APIs (as below)

1. POST http://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/albums (passed "Name" field with value)
2. POST http://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/albums (passed "Name" field with value)

As a response I get some "id". I believe that's the album id. But when I cross check using client by login in to user account -> Photos, I don't see any album created there.

Can somebody assist with the same?